# Error when creating page with customObject as a standardController with Tooling

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting, tooling-api

I want to create a visualforce page by using Tooling api and I am doing this like below :

```
@RemoteAction
    public static String createInlinePage(String objectName) {
        objectName = String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectName.trim());
        System.debug(objectName+'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~objectName');
        String salesforceHost = GetBaseUrlForInstance;
        System.debug(GetBaseUrlForInstance);
        String urlmy =  salesforceHost+'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/ApexPage';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(urlmy);
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        req.setBody('{"Name" : "'+objectName+'InlineAttachmentPage","Markup" : "<apex:page standardController=\''+objectName+'\' standardstylesheets=\'false\' cache=\'false\'><c:AttachPathInlineComponent objectId=\'{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}\'/></apex:page>","ControllerType" : "1","MasterLabel":"'+objectName+'InlineAttachmentPage","ApiVersion":"29.0"}');
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
        return res.getBody();
    }
```

This code is working fine for standard Object but not working for custom Object.

When I tried this for custom Object I got this error

```
{"message":"The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.: Name","errorCode":"FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION","fields":["Name"]}
```

Please guide me where I am wrong .

Comment: What name are you passing in?

Comment: Attachment_configuration__c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your comment, it is clear from the error string what the problem is -- you cannot pass in the name that you are.  the error says you cannot have consecutive `_` and using the API name for a custom object contains exactly that.  you can test this by hand by attempting to set the name of a new visualforce page to something like `TEST_NEWPAGE__C_DOUBLEUNDERSCORE`.  this will fail on save with the same error.  in order to create a new visualforce page you will have to either strip out/replace double underscores or pass in the display name of the object.

Comment: I can create the page from ui or from Eclipse with same name.

And if I will truncate anything from the name it will show "Object not found" error.

Comment: only the name of your page cannot have double underscores.  all other references to the object should be fine.